# 80's show or movie about Martian colonists, ships floating across the desert

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure if it's a film, a TV programme, whether it was from the 80's or the 70's, I think it was colonists on Mars, it had aliens, ships that floated across the desert (Mars I think) and that's about all I can remember, just something i watched when very little, would love to know what it's called. I seen somebody asked a very similar question, but the answer from what i could see was from some animated thing, this is not animated what I'm referring to.

Comment: Off to a good start there Chris, but we could use a few more points, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: _Return of the Jedi_ matches too - it's from the 80s, it has aliens and a spaceship floating across the desert. Ehm, a sail barge.

Comment: [Space: 1999](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072564/) was a TV series in the 1970s. It was set on the Moon, not Mars. I never watched it myself, but I seem to recall it had the "floating ships" you mention.

Comment: Dune might qualify as well

Comment: @NKCampbell I cannot believe one can watch Dune and remember the flying boxes while completely forgetting the worms.

Comment: Oddly, I was thinking Space: 1999 too, despite being on the Moon. One of the most memorable opening themes too.

Comment: Yeah thanks Guys, not return of the jedi, but i understand why it matched the criteria lol. Not Dune but again can see why people thought this. I shall check out space 1999, enemy is mine and Martian chronicles. again cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somewhat broad, but these two came to mind when you mentioned colonists, aliens and ships flying across deserts.

[Per the comments, it's the first one]

1. [The Martian Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles_(miniseries)) is a tv series with only 3 episodes about humans colonising on mars with existing martians already living there.
2. [Enemy Mine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089092/) Is more of a survival movie with an alien and human, but at the start and end it touched on colonisation and flying ships battling.

Comment: The Martian Chronicles by Ray Bradbury is likely it.  It had a number of stories from the story anthology of the same name.  One story dealt with the sand skimmers and made it into the TV show.

Comment: You know i think this is it, really happy to have finally found it and it wouldn't of been possible without this cool site. thanks. (Martian chronicles)